# Integrating LuaLaTeX into web project

Tags: luatex, mac, linux, minimal

For a web project I use LuaLaTeX to generate PDFs. I would like to do without a full-blown TeX distribution on the web server.

With pdfTeX this is easy: Call `pdflatex -recorder <tex_file>` and pack all the files listed, including the pdftex binary and pdflatex.fmt, into the directory with the .tex file.

Unfortunately, this does not work with LuaTeX, as a lot more happens in the background. Is there a possibility (and if so, how?) to integrate a minimal LuaLaTeX distribution into the project?

On top: target systems are primarily Linux servers and secondarily Macs for the developers. Is it possible to deliver different binaries for each system?

Comment: Interesting question. Related: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/163

Comment: One option would be to use the Island of TeX Docker images for TeX Live (https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive), another option is a package manager like Nix (https://nixos.wiki/wiki/TexLive).